# Troubleshooting a Java Web Start application and accessing log files

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I am launching a Java Web Start application which shuts down abruptly. Does anybody know how to access the logs for Java Web Start. Are there any known reasons for it to shut down abruptly?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should enable detailed trace logging [as explained on this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/plugin.html#gcexdf). The same page gives you the location of the log files;

> The trace file is saved into the `log` directory in the "Java Deployment Home" folder. That folder's location is specific to your operating system:
>
> - Windows XP: `%HOME%\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment`
> - Windows 7/Vista: `%APPDATA%\..\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment`
> - Linux/Solaris: `%HOME%/.java/deployment`

Comment: for example mine is under: C:\Users\mostafa.sho\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\log and mostafa.sho is my username in windows.

Answer (score 5):

On my Windows 10 computer, the log file is found at:

```
C:\Users\<MY USER>\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\log
```

Comment: Is there any guidance for OP regarding abrupt shutdowns you could offer?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why it would fail like that but you should be able to see where the logs by going to `File/Preferences/Advanced`.

You should also be  able to enable `java console` from the same location.

Answer (score 0):

Having `-Xmx` with a value too large was the cause of the issue for me.

Reducing the heap size resolved it.

Answer (score -1):

Having the `-XX:MaxPermSize` defined in your JNLP file can cause this issue on Linux and Mac machines. Removing that argument from the JNLP seems to fix the issue.

Check [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950624/stringindexoutofboundexcpetion-and-failure-to-launch-jnlp-in-mac-os#comment21057341_14950624).

Comment: Also, using -Xmx with a value too large will make java fail to start.

Comment: @SarelBotha - That shouldn't ideally happen given that the system has sufficient free memory to accommodate the max-heap size. The issue that you faced can be because of different reasons though. For e.g. on Linux, JVM fails to start if the OS's or the shell's virtual memory limit is limited (check: http://looselytyped.blogspot.in/2014/08/java-jvm-initialization-errors-on-linux.html)

Answer (score -1):

Try clearing the Java temporary internet files folder which is found in the Java Control Panel / General tab.  After doing this I was able to successfully relaunch my application through invoking the jnlp.