# How do you save the "Java Console" Log when a program crashes?

Tags: java, logging, error-logging

I have enable tracing and logging and show console enabled but the program I am using is crashing Java in a matter of minutes, is there anyway I can save the log directly to a file so when it crashes I can see what the last error was that was causing this? Also I have no access to the source code of this program.

Comment: Please share the command line used to start the app.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz javaws name.jnlp it launches with the console so I can read the logs but when it crashes the log disappears with it so I miss the last few errors or hints as to what is happening.

Comment: `javaws name.jnlp > app.log 2&>1` should work assuming your OS is Linux.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz sorry should have specified, crash is occurring on Windows 10

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11992492/2834978).

Answer (score 0):

Please add this in while starting java -**`XX:ErrorFile=filename%p.log.`**

Comment: where will the log file save? I do not see it in the program directory?

Comment: you can specify the full path where wanted to save the file

Comment: I tried "javaws name.jnlp -XX:ErrorFile=c:\filename%p.log"  and I am not getting any output to my C drive... the program crashes pretty often.